# Может ли git синхронизировать файлы на сервере

Tags: ftp, git

Не совсем понимаю как работает git, возможно ли так сделать что при работе на сервере через фтп сохранялись промежуточные изменения. Знающие люди объясните как что работает.
И не могу понять, неужели верстальщику нужно будет учить командную строку, неужели нельзя так что изменил кто-то файл и он автоматически сохранился. Не пойму я принцип работы, как-то он сильно сложно сделан. Неужели нет нормального клиента для гита как filezilla для работы через ftp.

Answer (score 3):

Представьте, что у вас на жестком диске папка с сайтом. Вы хотите вести историю изменений в этой папке и при необходимости иметь возможность откатиться назад или иметь несколько направлений разработки. Вот для этого и нужен гит. Обычно разработка ведется в нескольких ветках (branch), если это большая команда. Главной веткой является master. От него ответвляются другие ветки. Каждая ветка это по сути отдельно взятый снимок (snapshot) состояния репозитория в определенный момент времени. При переходе из одной ветки в другую может существенно меняться как структура папок и файлов, так и их содержимое. Любое изменение в ветке сразу становится известно гиту, но фиксация этого изменения происходит только если сделать git commit (это к вопросу о filezilla). Далее если нужно залить эти изменения на удаленный сервер, то сначала нужно сделать git pull (git pull origin название_ветки). Таким образом мы объединяем (merge) изменения с сервера (с текущей ветки) с локальными правками (в текущей ветке). Если при этом не произошло конфликтов (а такое бывает частенько в командном проекте), то делаем git push (заливаем изменения на сервер). Вот почти все, что нужно знать верстальщику о гите.

Comment: спасибо огромное очень хорошо написали, но наверно поздно я вот так и не понял возможно ли работать сразу на сервере. То есть поменяли на сервере и оно поменялось у нас...но совсем понимаю как происходит обмен файлами между машинами.

Comment: Я же написал. Для фиксации изменений в ветке нужно делать git commit. При этом не важно на сервере или на клиенте. Гит это децентрализованная система. То есть любая копия репозитория является полноценной и содержит в себе всю историю изменений. Для удобства на Windows лучше использовать клиент Tortoise Git. По крайней мере он удобен для коммитов и просмотра/сравнения изменений в файлах.

Comment: Сразу на сервере лучше не работать. Теряется все преимущество работы с гитом.